# Avoiding a null reference exception on a variable in a foreach loop that could be null

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I have a quadtree which has a remove method, and every time I remove an item from the game I call this method. The problem is that in the `foreach` loop, the child variable is null. How can I bypass this method so if the variable is null it won't give me an error?

```
private void CollapseChildren(RectangleTreeNode node)
    {
        foreach (RectangleTreeNode child in node.Children)
        {
            if (child == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            while (child.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                MoveUp(child.Items[0]);
            }
        }

        node.Children = null;
    }
```

Here's the remove method.

```
private void Remove(RectangleTreeNode node, RectangleTreeItem item)
    {
        node.Items.Remove(item);
        item.Parent = null;

        while (node != null)
        {
            node.ItemCount--;
            if (node.ItemCount < 6)
            {
                CollapseChildren(node);
            }
            node = node.Parent;
        }
    }
```

If the value is null then I shouldn't have to loop through the children in `nodes.Children` because if I do loop through then I get the error at the child variable. Meaning the node doesn't have a child.

Comment: If the value is null then I shouldn't have to loop through the children in nodes.Children because if I do loop through then I get the error at the child variable. Meaning the node doesn't have a child

Comment: Our company policy is never to set collections null like you do with `node.Children = null`, always create an empty collection like `node.Children = new RectangleTreeNode[0]`. This avoids errors and simplifies logic considerably

Comment: @DourHighArch: That is a good policy. Also, you can use *the same* empty array for every empty collection of that type, and avoid the memory allocation. It's an empty array, it's not going to change and one is as good as another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already checking whether or not each `child` is `null`.

If there's a risk of `node.Children` being `null`, then check for that too, before accessing it:

```
private void CollapseChildren(RectangleTreeNode node)
{
    if (node.Children == null)
        return;

    foreach (RectangleTreeNode child in node.Children)
    {
       ...
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Still get the error. So it must not be in the method.

Comment: I tried the answer below and it worked! I just had them in the wrong order

Comment: I missed the if(child == null) inside the foreach loop. I put it outside for some reason

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to check if `node.Children` is null prior to invoking the `foreach` loop, so your method becomes:

```
private void CollapseChildren(RectangleTreeNode node)
{
    if (node.Children == null)
    {
        // exit the method, or do whatever is appropriate when node.Children is null
        return;
    }

    foreach (RectangleTreeNode child in node.Children)
    {
        if (child == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        while (child.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            MoveUp(child.Items[0]);
        }
    }

    node.Children = null;
}
```